# Javascript : How to access to the data imported from the controller with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, list, view, controller

I am beginner and I need to get a list of the object "Event"(OrderId , Date) from the controller MVC to Javascript in the view , and It is like a list of string , it shows me "undefined".
On the side of the controller I see that it's correct!
I searched and I do not find my error, I try with # and without also with foreach but I think that it's not true, so thanks you to help me !!

The controller :

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public JsonResult getListEvent() {
   IList<Event> ListEvent = new List<Event>();
   ListEvent = DeserializeElement();
   return Json(new { ListEvent = ListEvent }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private List<Event> DeserializeElement () {
        List<Event> lt = new List<Event>();
    document.Load("eventXml.xml");
    foreach (XmlNode item in document.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
        Event e = new Event();
        e.OrderId = int.Parse(item.Attributes[0].Value);
        e.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Attributes[1].Value);
        lt.Add(e);
    }
    return lt;
}
```

and the view :

```
function GetListEvent() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/getListEvent",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            alert( data[0].OrderId);
            alert('#'+ data[1].Date);
            for (var item in data ) {
                alert('#' + data[item]);
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert('eror');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much but after searching I discovered that it is an object in another,

So, I must write :

```
alert(data.ListEvent[0].OrderId);
```

and not

```
alert(data[0].OrderId);
```

and I don't need "#" ;